# What is the correct way to load images (and other assets) in an Angular 11 project?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After upgrading to Angular 11, I encountered some problems regarding asset paths in my project.

I want to know **the correct way** for adding assets in angular projects.

Is it

```
src: url('/assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Bold.woff') format('woff');
```

Or

```
src: url('assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Bold.woff') format('woff');
```

Or

```
src: url('../../../../assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Bold.woff') format('woff');
```

Also, someone told me if I use relative path (the third one), it will cause problems in production builds on the server. Is that true? and if it is, why is that?

Moreover, you would think the first and second example don't really differ. That's not what `Angular CLI` thinks. Sometimes it only accepts the first one as valid and throws the following error when second option is used:

```
Error: ./src/app/app.component.scss
Module Error (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: /home/styles/kit/_nunitosans.scss:20:2: Can't resolve '../styles/kit/assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Bold.woff' in '/home/newsha/didex/didex-auth-front/src/app'
```

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Newsha, Angular copy the folder 'assets' in the root of your project (the folder where "index.html" is created, so you can **not** use `../../....`. Using `/assets/...` makes that don't depend from your "base href", using `assets/...`, makes that if you change the "base href" (e.g. you has a multilanguage application and for Spanish your base href is `/es-ES` Angular try to find from this "href"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

inside angular.json you have this part of configuration:

```
"assets": [
   "src/assets"
],
```

When *ng build --prod* is run, the paths you included here, will be included in the final build as well, so you will be able to access them on the server. You can add any other folders as well. That's why the correct form of pointing to files inside your angular app is using the absolute path like this: *src: url('/assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Bold.woff') format('woff');*

Comment: I am not sure this is entirely correct because when using the absolute path notation `/assets/fonts...` you are preventing the browser from prepending base-url. A more appropriate solution would be to use `assets/fonts...`